# Chromecast custom selector dialog

Tags: android, chromecast

Is there a way to make a custom chromecast selector dialog? I have been looking through the documentation and can't find anything on how to do this.

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that:

1. First, extend [MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment.html), and call that, say, `MyChooserDialogFragment`.
2. Next, extend the `MediaRouteDialogFactory` (call that, say,  MyMediaRouteDialogFactory) and override the method `onCreateChooserDialogFragment()`. In there, you need to return an instance of `MyChooserDialogFragment`:

   ```
   public MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment onCreateChooserDialogFragment() {
       return new MyChooserDialogFragment();
   }
   ```
3. Finally, set this factory on the action provider:

   ```
   mediaRouteActionProvider.setDialogFactory(new MyMediaRouteDialogFactory());
   ```

Comment: This works but I need to actually modify the layout of this dialog. Like I need to add other components to it like a close image.An style it.

Comment: When you extend MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment, you can override onCreateDialog() and there you can build and return your own custom Dialog container.